# Add Up/Down buttons to UITableView navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, ios4

Many apps, including Apple's own native Mail.app on the iPhone implement an Up/Down button in the detail view which allows for quick and easy browsing. I wish to create such an interface in my own app, but am struggling to do so. So far I've setup a segmented control which links to an action in my navigation bar, but I'm struggling with what to put in the action to make the detail view for the table update when the user presses the "Up" button or "Down" button to navigate to the item before or after the current one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: cells displaying uitext fields called from an nsmutablearray

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have your data set up, but why can't you hook into your existing code? What are you doing in your existing code to refresh the detail view when a user selects a row in master view table? Can't you just call that method directly?

It's hard to give specific advice without more detailed information on your current design.

Comment: Questions should be asked in the comments, not posted as an answer.

Comment: Agree, but in this case the answer was in the form of a question ;). I state that if the master/detail code is already working, then it should be possible to call the same method that is already being used to refresh the detail. Without more specific information on the implementation, that's as close to an answer as anyone can come.

Comment: Without more specific information, how can you post an answer in the first place?